# Triggers, Static Variable and Debug Log

Tags: salesforce

I have following trigger on Account object:

```
trigger triggerCounter on Account (before insert) {
/* this trigger is used to record the number of times trigger is called for a bunch of records */
/*countTriggerExecution.count =countTriggerExecution.count+1;
System.debug('Trigger has run' +countTriggerExecution.count);*/
}
```

And following class:

```
public class countTriggerExecution{
/* this class provides a static counter to count the numver of times a trigger is executes */
public static Integer count=0;
}
```

When uploading 800 Account records via workbench and not checking 'Process records asynchronously via Bulk API'  I get 4 entries in the Debug log and can see that the value of the static variable in not maintained across these 4 logs. However when I check 'Process records asynchronously via Bulk API' then there is only one Trigger debug log record and also the state of the static variable is maintained.

Can anyone please help in in understanding that why in the first case 4 debug logs records and the state of the static variable is not maintained?

Answer (score 0):

The Bulk api uses a batch size of up to 10,000 records, while the other APIs break your batches up to chunks of 200 records and sends them separately to be processed, so that would appear as 4 separate processes.  The bulk api sends an entire batch to the server and then processes the records after that. See https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Loading_Large_Data_Sets_with_the_Force.com_Bulk_API for more info on the bulk api and how it works.